# Getting data from multiple tables in mysql using joins ends in wrong data

Tags: mysql

I need to select the customer and product code and the date on which the order was made, but I'm having some trouble with the join orders.

[image]

My SQL select:

```
select c.customerNumber, p.productCode, o.orderDate as data_compra
    from customers as c inner join orders as o
    inner join products as p
    where p.productCode =
                any (
                        select p2.productCode from products as p2
                        inner join orders as o
                        inner join orderdetails as odt
                        where o.orderNumber = odt.orderNumber and
                        p2.productCode = odt.productCode
                    )
    and o.orderNumber = 
                any (
                        select o2.orderNumber from orders as o2
                        inner join orderdetails as odt
                        where o.orderNumber = odt.orderNumber and
                        p.productCode = odt.productCode
                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple joins should do what you want:

```
select
    c.customerNumber,
    d.productCode,
    o.orderDate
  from customer c
  join orders o on o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
  join orderdetails d on d.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you're asking to inner join two tables but not specifying the relationship. You need to do so SQL can relate and match the rows in each table.

You do this with the ON keyword.

I suggest you watch this [video](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/querying-with-transactsql-10530?l=TjT07f87_9804984382#) and read this [article](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/amp/) before continuing

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will check it